# How do I get a for loop to work on all the worksheets in my workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

Simple question, and I feel like an idiot for not knowing this. What happened was I imported some data from several word docs, and it left me with some extraneous data on all of the sheets. I want to go through and have it delete the top three rows of each sheet automatically (normally I wouldn't mind, but for 100+ sheets it is a bit annoying).

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
Sub delete_rows()

Dim delRange As Range
Dim wkSheet As Worksheet

For Each wkSheet In ThisWorkbook

   Set delRange = Rows("1:3")
   delRange.Delete
Next wkSheet

End Sub
```

I get this error kicked back:

"runtime error '438':

object doesn't support this property or method"

The error comes up at the start of the for loop.

Any chance I could get some help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the Worksheet type instead of a variable. Also you are not referencing the Worksheets collection in your `For Each` loop.

```
For Each wkSheet in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    '...
Next wkSheet
```

Also, you don't need to use a variable if you are just deleting 3 rows. You can do directly:

```
Rows("1:3").Delete
```